# Display totals for Label (or simply display a string) inside a chart in Chart.js

Tags: charts, chart.js

On Chart.js i need to show some text (for instance the total for that label's data) over the bars (not over each bar).
For example, let's say these are some months with some data for people who ate pizza and people who ate hamburgers over x months.
Now i want to show the sum of people who ate pizza and hamburgers for every month (in the example below 1100 and 1300). How can i write something in the center of a month?

```
    1100    |    1300    |
       _    |   _   _    |
   _  | |   |  | | | |   |
  | | | |   |  | | | |   |
  | | | |   |  | | | |   |
   January  |  February  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. It's possible to do that with an external plugin called
[chartjs annotation](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation)

```
annotation: {

    // Should be one of: afterDraw, afterDatasetsDraw, beforeDatasetsDraw
    drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw', // (default)


    annotations: [

                {

        type: 'line',
        mode: 'vertical',
        scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
        value: 'January',
        borderColor: 'transparent',
        borderWidth: 0,

                    label: {
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)',
                        fontSize: 10,
                        fontStyle: "bold",
                        fontColor: "#fff",
                        xPadding: 6,
                        yPadding: 6,
                        cornerRadius: 6,
                        position: "center",
                        xAdjust: 0,
                        yAdjust: -80,
                        enabled: true,
                        content: "Totals etc"
                    }

                }


            ]
        }
```